# Swift - Generate Barcode Error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

I have the codes below to generate a barcode on swift:

```
qrImg.image = GenerateCodeImages().barCode(code: "ABCDEFGHI ABCDEFGHI ABCDEFGHI ABCDEFGHI ABCDEFGHI ABCDEFGHI ABCD")
```

It crashes ([error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhnRG.png)) when it gets to `if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {` and gives out `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

```
     func barCode(code: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = code.data(using: .ascii)

        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
            filter.setDefaults()
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return convertToUIImage(output: output)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
    
    func convertToUIImage(output: CIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return nil }
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return image
    }
```

It doesn't always crash. It works well when I try displaying "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678". I just can't figure out what the difference is. ~_~ TYIA.

Comment: Is there a message log in console when it crashes?

Comment: the messages in the console are:

`2020-06-30 15:27:10.102676+0800 Navigation Controller Test[8477:298776] Failed to set (borderWidth) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [<UIView 0x7fc541e06aa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderWidth.
2020-06-30 15:27:38.422315+0800 Navigation Controller Test[8477:298776] Metal API Validation Enabled
(lldb) `

but these were generated even before it hit the crash point. ~_~

Comment: in addition to this, I tried generating `ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ` and it crashes. The weird thing is that it doesn't crash if I generate `123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890` first before generating `ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ `. Still haven't gotten the String with spaces to work though.